# Core data and sorting after a join condition

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data

I have 3 tables in my core data tables.
**Item table**: items, which has an ID column and a connection to a properties table.
**Properties table**: it has a propertyValue column and a connection to item table and a connection to property table.
**Property table**: it has a propertyName column and a connection to properties table.

The property table contains a propertyName called "price".
The properties table contains a propertyValue "20" for the property "price".
Do you think I can sort the Items table by price?

I am using a `NSFetchedResultsController` and I am creating a `NSFetchRequest` for it.
I have tried to write a NSSortDescriptor with a comparator block object for the `NSFetchRequest`. It isn't working. After this I tried to write a NSSortDescriptor without any selector or block object, I just setup a key called "dealPrice" and created a category on the Item managed object with a method called `- (NSString *)dealPrice`. It wasn't working neither.

Do you know any other method? Or do you know the solution?

Comment: You should stop thinking about databases and tables when thinking about CoreData. [Getting Started With Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GettingStartedWithCoreData/_index.html)

Comment: See Also: [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide: Object Modeling](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW2)

Comment: Ok, I know I have to stop, I've read all the documents you linked in. So let's change the word 'table' word to word 'entity' :)

Comment: Which entity `Item` or `Property` objects will populate the tableview i.e. which entity is set of the fetched results controller's fetch request entity? That is a key detail to know how to configure the sort descriptor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've obviously got a bad case of SQL fever. Your trying to treat Core Data like an SQL wrapper and that is messing everything up.

Core Data is not SQL. Entities are not tables. Objects are not rows. Attributes are not columns. Relationships are not joins. Core Data is an object graph management system that may or may not persist the object graph and may or may not use SQL far behind the scenes to do so. Trying to think of Core Data in SQL terms will cause you to completely misunderstand Core Data and result in much grief and wasted time.

A Core Data datamodel should not be configured depending on the needs of the UI or any other non-data requirement. Instead, it should accurately model/simulate the real world objects, events or conditions that the app deals with.

In this case, you are modeling:

1. A type of property that has a name and a price.
2. An item denoted by an id of some kind
3. A relationship between one or more particular property instances and one or more instances of item.

Therefore, your data model only needs two entities connected by a relationship. You don't need a "join" because the relationship handles the connection between the two entities automatically.

The simplest model has just a one-to-one relationship:

```
Item{
  id:string
  property<-->Property.item
}

Property{
  name:string
  price:number
  item<-->Item.property
}
```

If each `Item` object can have several associated `Property` objects  then you would have:

```
Item{
  id:string
  properties<-->>Property.item
}

Property{
  name:string
  price:number
  item<<-->Item.properties
}
```

If each `Property` object can have several associated `Item` objects:

```
Item{
  id:string
  property<<-->Property.items
}

Property{
  name:string
  price:number
  items<-->>Item.properties
}
```

How you configure your sort descriptors depends on the details of the relationships and which entity's objects your tableview will display.

Comment: Good point of view, in this model, I would like to change the 'price' property in the Property entity to 'value' and then, a 'name' property can have the 'price' string and the 'value' property can have a sum. In this case, how you would like to sort the items by price?

Comment: So, in my point, each item can have multiple Properties and each Property can have multiple items.

Comment: Changing the relationships to `to-many-to-many` doesn't really change much although it can make things like predicates and sorts more complicated. The key to good design is to look closely at the actual logical problem the app is intended to solve and then to create entities and relationships as close to the real-world things as possible.

Comment: I would recommend avoiding a name like `value` because of Objective-C global open name space. There are to many things in the API called `value` already so you might get a naming collision. Try something like `propValue` for safety. Also, does the real-world `Property` object actually have both a `price` and `value` attributes. Most things do not. Usually the price is the value and vice-versa. Make sure your not adding an attribute just as an implementation detail unless you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 0):

What I would first recommend is to stop thinking about CoreData like a database.  It is NOT a database.  The things you call "tables" are actually Entities.  Think of them as objects, that have properties and relationships to other objects.  Think about making your data model as simple as possible.  Do not try to optimize your structure for database performance etc.  The actual backing schema is not under your control.

With that in mind, from what you've posted about your data model, it seems like you should be able to collapse into at least 2 entities instead of 3 (perhaps 1 but not sure without seeing your entire data model).  Then, you should be able to do a simple fetch on the Items entity with a predicate that sorts on a property of it's related object.

Comment: Ok, my problem is that, I can't use a trigger. So let's say, if I have a property which always changes, how can I force Core Data to update an other property just before I fetch it?

Comment: Read up on KVO, it might be useful from what I understand about your above comment, but I don't fully understand what you mean.  Can you describe it with more detail or in another way?

Comment: @infinity -- The managed object context manages the managed objects using key-value observing. The data model informs the context how everything fits together. When you make a change in any managed object, the context observes the change and then sends a notification to any object that has registered for notification of changes e.g. a fetched results controller. Your making this way to hard. Core Data handles all the things you are trying to automatically.

Comment: @Paul - I think I know KVO, I think :) @TechZen - thank you, I start to understand this concept

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your real object model is and *entity* named **Deal** with an *attribute* named "price".

Comment: yes, that's true, but I think, this isn't important in this case.. :)